# Icefaces 1.8.2 Pages without session

Tags: session, scalability, icefaces

I have an enterprise application where there are 2 types of users:
 - Guests (who may only visit limited pages)
 - Members (who sign in)
Entire application is built using icefaces 1.8.2.

Due to scalability issues I want guest pages **not** to create sessions. One solution is to use **just-ice.jar** instead of **icefaces.jar**, but it is very costly in terms of development to re-write JSP pages.

Is there any easy solution to simply prevent icefaces to create session and D2D rendering for specific pages?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in standard icefaces web application.

Try Icefaces 1.8 from [svn trunk](http://anonsvn.icesoft.org/repo/icefaces/trunk/icefaces). Serious memory leak in sessions management was fixed few months ago. Look at http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/ICE-8833. At this moment this version used with JSF-RI is very stable.

Additionaly move common part of data to application bean and change quest pages to request scope. It should work with few houndred parallel users.

Finally test it under high load and look in VisualVM for memory leaks or locked threads. Some simple minor tweaks may be needed.